# I am wrongly replacing declaring values in my javascript code: get ed static value

Tags: javascript

I have this code

I'm trying to change the variables here, since I use the same name for another script and it does a conflict

```
<div id="clockdiv">
    <div class="smalltext">
        <span class="minutes"></span>mins
        <span class="seconds"></span>secs
    </div>
</div>
```

So I wanted to pick "minutes-countdown" and "seconds-countdown".

But when I try to replace the variables in the following code, I couldn't make it work.

I must replace it badly since a lot of variables appear to have the same name which is confusing to me, since I'm quite a beginner with javascript :/

The best thing I managed to do is making the span displaying, but with a static value "ed" instead of countdown

Any idea on how to replace the variables correctly?

Your help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  return {
    'total': t, 'minutes': minutes, 'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline;

if(window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty('deadline')){
deadline = window.localStorage.getItem('deadline');
} 

else {
var timeInMinutes = 30;
var timeInSeconds = 00;
  deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + timeInMinutes*60*1000 +  timeInSeconds*1000);
  window.localStorage.setItem('deadline',deadline);
}
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For information, this is how I replaced the variables which got me the "ed" static value:

```
<div id="clockdiv">
    <div class="smalltext">
        <span class="minutes-countdown"></span>mins
        <span class="seconds-countdown"></span>secs
    </div>
</font></strong>
</div>
.</li> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  return {
    'total': t, 'minutes-countdown': minutes, 'seconds-countdown': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes-countdown');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds-countdown');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline;

if(window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty('deadline')){
deadline = window.localStorage.getItem('deadline');
} 

else {
var timeInMinutes = 30;
var timeInSeconds = 00;
  deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + timeInMinutes*60*1000 +  timeInSeconds*1000);
  window.localStorage.setItem('deadline',deadline);
}
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```